# MySQL displaying wrong time for some timezones

Tags: mysql, timezone, convert-tz

I am using MySQL 5.1.34 community server.
I have taken the MySQL timezone description tables from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html).

Now for some timezones the time displayed by MySQL is wrong, because of wrong "day light saving" calculation for these time zones.

Ex: 
The query

```
select convert_tz(now(),'GMT','Australia/Sydney');
```

is giving wrong result.

Wrong time is displayed for the following timezones:

```
America/Sao_Paulo  
America/Caracas  
America/Buenos_Aires  
Asia/Karachi  
Asia/Dhaka  
Australia/Adelaide  
Australia/Sydney
```

But for all other timezones(except the ones above)  the "day light saving" calculation is perfect and it displays  the correct time.

What am I missing here ? Updating to a later version of MySQL will help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My timezones table were not updated.
Just updated them from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html) and now everything is working fine.

Comment: This doesn't work for me at all, Debian 8 has the right tzdata loaded and is giving the correct result when typing date but convert_tz gives current timezone plus 1 hour. what is going on between OS and mysql?